# When are coordinate rings separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, separable-extension

Let $k$ be a field, and $f\in k[x]$ be a polynomial. Consider the coordinate ring $k[x]/(f)$. This is a $k$-algebra. I have seen people using the statement that this $k$-algebra is separable iff $f$ is a separable polynomial. Is that even true? Why or why not?

Comment: What have you tried on your own to prove this? Are the definitions clear to you? In particular, do you know how finite-dimensional **commutative** separable algebras look like?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Commutative seperable $k$-algebras are the same as finite products of matrix algebras over finite-dimensional separable field extensions of $k$, at least that is what nlab says. Also, apparently a finite field extension $L/k$ is seperable iff $L$ is a seperable $k$-algebra. This answers my question affirmatively. But with my definition of seperability (A $k$-algebra $A$ is called seperable if for every field extension $K$ of $k$ the $k$-algebra $A\otimes_k K$ is semisimple), I do not see why this holds.